# JQGrid is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am trying to use JQGrid as in http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. But it's not displaying anything. Please help me to get this working.

```html
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script  type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("#s3list").jqGrid({
              url:'search.php?q=1',
              datatype: "json",
              width: 700, colNames:[
              'Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
              colModel:[
                  {name:'id',index:'id', width:65},
                  {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90,
                      searchoptions:{
                        dataInit:function(el) {
                            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                        } }},
                  {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
                  {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right"},
                  {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right", stype:'select',
                      editoptions:{value:":All;0.00:0.00;12:12.00;20:20.00;40:40.00;60:60.00;120:120.00"}},
                  {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right"}
                  {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
              ], 
              rowNum:10,
              mtype: "POST",
              rowList:[10,20,30],
              pager: '#s3pager',
              sortname: 'id',
              viewrecords: true,
              rownumbers: true,
              sortorder: "desc",
              gridview : true,
              caption:"Toolbar Search Example"
          }); 
          jQuery("#s3list").jqGrid('navGrid','#s3pager',
              {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});
          jQuery("#s3list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#s3pager", {
              caption:"Toggle",
              title:"Toggle Search Toolbar",
              buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
              onClickButton:function(){
                  mygrid[0].toggleToolbar()
              }
          });
          jQuery("#s3list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#s3pager", {
              caption:"Clear",
              title:"Clear Search",
              buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
              onClickButton:function(){
                  mygrid[0].clearToolbar()
              }
          }); 
          jQuery("#s3list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
      });
</script>    
</head> 
<body>
   <table id="s3list"></table> 
      <div id="s3pager"></div> 
      <div id="filter" style="margin-left:30%;display:none">Search Invoices</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try import jqgrid library. Your example is working here. http://jsfiddle.net/vwb1c0mk/143/

Comment: You should format the code so that people could read it. The current code contains **syntax error**: missing comma between `total` and `note` column  in `colModel`. It is was an typing error, then you should include JSON data returned from he `url`. You should include in all questions about jqGrid the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the jqGrid javascript library before you can use those functions.
Please download the scripts from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 and add them to your script. (Load the script right after you load jQuery)

or just add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqgrid/4.6.0/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

Hope that helped :)